# http_proxy and https_proxy are set to http:// and https:// in Debian, which causes a lot of problems

Tags: debian, shell, proxy

I recently installed Debian 10 from the Original ISO-files. But I got some small and at the same time huge weird problem. For some reason, `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` are set to `http://` and `https://`. This causes a lot of problems with different scripts, and I either have to set those shell variables manually or via `.bashrc`. But it's the same for every new user, and also for root.

Why is this set? And where is this set? I've looked for it in all of `/etc`, but found nothing.

This is nothing that affects Firefox or Chrome, but only shell commands (e.g. `wget` fails until I unset the variable or set it empty).